# Regex for backup files that contains date format and .zip extension in bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash, file, git-bash

I am new to bash and need help selecting files with a particular date format and .zip extension. I would like to use a regex to select the right files. Below is the format of the files i wish to select

```
2017-Apr-13--2315.zip
```

So basically the year, the month in 3 letter words, day, and the time the backup occurred, which is the 4 figures just before the .zip extension.
I am struggling to get it right on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Eventually, i want to select the right files and delete all backups but leave the latest 6 backups. The command i am using is below

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | tac | tail -n +7 | xargs rm -rf
```

But there are other files in the directory that are not backups. So i need to select the right files with the regex matching the file format i provided above.

Comment: Are you using `find` command?

Comment: So, what is the regex you are using? What does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following `regex` may work with `find`:

```
find . -regextype egrep -iregex '.*/[0-9]{4}-[a-z]{3}-[0-9]{2}--[0-9]{4}\.zip$'
```

To delete matching file, you can use:

```
find . -regextype egrep -iregex '.*/[0-9]{4}-[a-z]{3}-[0-9]{2}--[0-9]{4}\.zip$' -delete
```